# How to get all results that contain a certain string (explained more in post)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So, let's say I put "h" in a post form and I have 5 things in my data base:

**1st Entry - Name: Hello**

**2nd Entry - Name: Height**

***3rd, 4th, 5th entries do not have a word that has "h" in them***

How would I make it return all of the ones that include the string provided (like Hello and Height)

Here is my current setup:

```
app.post('/search/full', async (req, res) =>{
  const URLs = await shortURL.find({
      "short": {
        "$regex": req.body.fullURLSearch,
        "$options": "i"
      }
    })
    res.render('searchFull', {
        fullURLsearch: URLs
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want case insensitive query, you can do this (if you want case sensitive query, just remove `"$options": "i"`):

```
db.collection.find({
  "field": {
     "$regex": "YourQueryString",
     "$options": "i"
  }
})
```

Here is the working snippet: https://mongoplayground.net/p/F6oSaf8P7lb

Comment: I added working snippet to the answer, so you can check it.

Comment: Just like above, doesn't work but I'll use this if I do fix it :)

Comment: Can you give me your testing query? What are you testing? URL string?

Comment: Ok yes sure, let me put it on Pastebin for cleaner layout.

Comment: Add it to your question.

Comment: Done. Now what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231883/discussion-between-sirstopit-and-nenad-milosavljevic).

Answer (score 1):

You don't really give much to go on, but based on your question I can assume something like this might work:

```
db.collection.find({field:/H/}})
```

naturally replace the `H` with a variable as required

Comment: Ok so I've done this: `const URLs = await shortURL.find({ full: /req.body.fullURLSearch/ })` but it doesn't work when I enter https://, nor does it work when I enter T for the short URL find but does work when I do `/t/`.